# Android Studio - Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, crash-reports, android-studio-2.3

This **ISSUE** persists from last 3 to 4 days. I'm using Android Studio - 2.3.2. But in previous version I had same **ISSUE**. The whole ERROR is like below.

`Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
Cause:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)`

Android Studio also crashes frequently.
When Android Studio crashes it gives ERROR like below.
I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

[image]

What I have tried.

1. Installed new, latest and fresh Android Studio.
2. Made another folder for project work space and checked out latest project code from SVN.
3. Tried to CLEAN, REBUILD and RESTART Android Studio several times.

I think there should be some problem in **Ubuntu** but don't know how to solve it. Genuine help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to update Ubuntu? Your version is very old and pretty near to the end of support, actual stable LTS is 17.04.

Comment: Thanks bro. Let me update it. I hope after updating, ISSUE will get sorted.@MartinRevert

Comment: I have seen this error go away after I killed off other RAM consuming processes on a 4 gig box